# JavaScript scroll but not window

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I was learning simple web scraping and came across the necessity to scroll on a flexbox, specifically, the box that pops up when I click to see profiles that liked a specific photo on Instagram.
How can I scroll automatically in this kind of window?

I know that

```
window.scrollBy(...);
```

scrolls the full page, but I want to scroll the specific region of the flexbox. This seems fairly simple, but I couldn't come across it on a search...

Thank you.

Comment: Select the element that has the overflowing content and then scroll it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollBy